# How to do in-page citation in LaTex (Overleaf)?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, xelatex

In many research papers, I have seen in-page citations for websites and technologies like this,[image]

How to do this using LaTex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is called a footnote](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes), and the command has the same name:

```
\textit{YikYak}\footnote{\url{https://www.yikyak.com/about}, accessed:}
```

You’ll need to use [the `hyperref` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref) for the footnote to be linked as it is in the screenshot (and to be able to use `\url`).